# Capybara - Chromium driver with Selenium socks proxy not working but poltergeist works

Tags: ruby, capybara, chromium, socks, headless

Using `Chromium 62.0.3168.0` I have confirmed it uses my `socks5` proxy when running `chrome` directly: `./chrome --headless --remote-debugging-port=9222 --proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:9055 http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com` but when I try to run through Capybara I earn an error:

```
SOCKSError::ServerFailure: general SOCKS server failure
```

How do I get Capybara to use `headless_chrome` through my socks proxy?

My chrome Capybara setup that isn't working:

```
Capybara.default_driver = :headless_chromium
Capybara.register_driver :headless_chromium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, {
    browser: :chrome,
    desired_capabilities: Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
      "chromeOptions" => {
        'binary' => "#{ENV['HOME']}/chromium/src/out/Default/chrome",
        'args' => ["no-sandbox", "disable-gpu", "headless",
                   "proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:9055"]
      }
    )
  })
end
```

If I remove the `proxy-server` arg from the above code, the `:headless_chromium` driver works but doesnt use the socks proxy.

Here is my Capybara setup for `poltergeist` that does succesfully use the socks proxy:

```
Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {
    :phantomjs => Phantomjs.path,
    :phantomjs_options => ["--proxy-type=socks5", "--proxy=127.0.0.1:9055"]
  })
end
```